# How to connect chain links to the axle

Tags: building, technic

In my project I want append two 21 chain links to the axle 12.
Is this any axle connector with knob ending?

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what it is that you are trying to do? Perhaps some pictures of what you have tried already and where you are running into trouble?

Comment: I add picture later, because at this moment I am on work and I have only phone. I want build castle door but I have problem how to connect chains to the axle, not axle endings, but aprox. 4 studs from axle end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something a little similar to this:

[image: Axle with chain]

There was a similar setup in the Bespin Cloud City scene that used a string attached to two studs that was wound around an axle in the same way.

As Phil B. suggests, adding an additional round plate on top of the chain will provide you with a bit more support for the stud, at the possible expense of making the winding thicker - it will tend to wrap around the plates then.

Comment: You might want to add an extra 2x2 round plate to the top of the plate w chain to prevent the chain from coming loose - so sandwich the chain between the two plates